# Adding Quick Launch links in Sharepoint 2007 for new dashboards added via a wsp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint wsp file in which I create two new dashboards (both the aspx files and their metadata setup are included in my elements.xml file).

The wsp deploys fine, and I can see my two new dashboards if I click on 'Dashboards' on the quick launch bar.  However, I would like to include links to these two new dashboards in the quick launch bar.

How is this done?  Any suggestions/links would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection ql = yourSpWeb.Current.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode navNode = new SPNavigationNode("New Link", 
                                 "relative/path/to/yourpage.aspx", true);
ql.AddAsFirst(navNode);
```

(If you want to add child nodes then use navNode.Children.AddAsFirst)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Feature Activation handler to programmatically add the links that you want to the Quick Launch Bar.